# Set detailTextLabel with related data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm sure the answer is easy but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have two one-to-many related tables:

```
Entities       Users    <-->   Kind  
attributes     userName        kindName  

Relationship   hasKinds        forUser
```

In my `UITableViewCell` I have set the TextLabel to user, and I try to set the `detailTextLabel` to the related kind but it wont let me.

Here is the code:

```
 - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Users *users = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = users.userName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [users.hasKinds.kindName];
}
```

The error is:

> Property 'kindName' not found on object of type 'NSSet *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that `users.hasKinds` isn't of expected type `Kind` but of type `NSSet *`.
Check the `users.hasKinds` property/method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship between users and kind. It seams like the users can have more than one kind. So if you are asking for the kinds of a user you get back a set with all the kinds.

You could now print a string containing all kinds of a user like so:

```
 - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Users *users = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = users.userName;

    NSMutableString *kindsString = [NSMutableString string];
    for (Kind *kind in user.hasKinds) {
        [kindsString appendString:kind.kindName];
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = kindsString;
}
```

Comment: Now it works. I forgot that the property of hasKinds was a NSSet putting the content into a string solved the problem. Thank you all.

Comment: @Irene Check the answer which helped as correct so that other who are searching for the same answer have a better chance to find it.